# JQuery Opacity Filter

Tags: jquery, opacity

I have a simple script, that basically adjust the opacity items of unordered list items to 0.1 if they do not match the selection.

```
$('ul.filter li a').click(function() {
    var getvalue = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('.portfolioThumbs li.all').animate({opacity:0.1});
    $('.portfolioThumbs li.'+getvalue).animate({opacity:1});
    return false;
});
```

How can I add to or modify this, so those opacity items at 0.1 you cannot click?

Comment: give some html so we can help...because we don't know what are child what are descendents etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/pointer-events) css property.

```
$('ul.filter li a').click(function() {
    var getvalue = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('.portfolioThumbs li.all').animate({opacity:0.1}).css('pointer-events', 'none');
    $('.portfolioThumbs li.'+getvalue).animate({opacity:1}).css('pointer-events', 'auto');;
    return false;
});
```

Note: `pointer-events` for HTML elements is only supported in Chrome 2.0+, Firefox 3.6+ and Safari 4.0+, not supported in IE and Opera.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just add a class when you set opacity

`$('.portfolioThumbs li.all').animate({opacity:0.1}).addClass('addedClass');`

and then

```
$('.portfolioThumbs li.addedClass').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

or you can simply prevent click without adding additional class as well (as they have one)

```
$('.portfolioThumbs li.all').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

BTW why do you want to prevent a click on the li items.. is there an anchor tag that is inside these li that you want to prevent click on?

Comment: The addedClass would work - but that adds the class to all list items. If I do the same on the line $('.portfolioThumbs li.'+getvalue).animate({opacity:1}); - then that adds the class to all opacity 1 items - so effectively this would work, just reversed?